# Modify the code of the example Plane partition by Jang Soo Kim from "texample.net"

Tags: tikz-pgf

From the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470653/cubes-drawing-code-modification), is it possible to make a lower cube position void, to create this drawing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% to suppresses (hide) navigation symbols bar
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% Three counters
\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{y}
\newcounter{z}
% The angles of x,y,z-axes
\newcommand\xaxis{210}
\newcommand\yaxis{-30}
\newcommand\zaxis{90}
% The top side of a cube
\newcommand\topside[3]{
  \fill[fill=yellow, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (0,1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The left side of a cube
\newcommand\leftside[3]{
  \fill[fill=green, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (210:1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The right side of a cube
\newcommand\rightside[3]{
  \fill[fill=blue, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (-30:1) --(0,-1)--(0,0);
}
% The cube 
\newcommand\cube[3]{
  \topside{#1}{#2}{#3} \leftside{#1}{#2}{#3} \rightside{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand\planepartition[1]{
 \setcounter{x}{-1}
  \foreach \a in {#1} {
\addtocounter{x}{1}
\setcounter{y}{-1}
\foreach \b in \a {
  \addtocounter{y}{1}
  \setcounter{z}{-1}
 \ifnum \b>0
  \foreach \c in {1,...,\b} {
   \addtocounter{z}{1}
   \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}
}\fi}}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\planepartition{{2,1,2,1,2,1,2},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{2,1,2,1,2,1,2}}%1st column from back to front{row1,... from left to right}%0 is the same as 2% it does not allow void for 0
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is sufficient to build layer by layer *(floor by floor)* from the lowest to the highest.

To do this, I modified the loop by adding an optional argument that is set to `0` by default. This allows you to keep the old syntax for previous graphics.

This optional argument is simply added to the `z` counter in the loop:

```
\addtocounter{z}{#1}
```

By default, this argument is `0` and builds the partition like the old code, i.e. on the ground floor.

- When this argument is equal to `1`, it builds a partition one floor above.
- when it is equal to `2`, it builds two floors above, etc.

It is always possible to build several layers *(or floors)* at the same time as in the old code.

```
\newcommand\planepartition[2][0]{
 \setcounter{x}{-1}
  \foreach \a in {#2} {
        \addtocounter{x}{1}
        \setcounter{y}{-1}
            \foreach \b in \a {
            \addtocounter{y}{1}
            \setcounter{z}{-1}
            \addtocounter{z}{#1} %partition of the desired floor (layer)
            \ifnum \b>0
            \foreach \c in {1,...,\b} {
                \addtocounter{z}{1}
                \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}
      }\fi
    }
  }
}
```

[image: cubes]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% to suppresses (hide) navigation symbols bar
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% Three counters
\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{y}
\newcounter{z}
% The angles of x,y,z-axes
\newcommand\xaxis{210}
\newcommand\yaxis{-30}
\newcommand\zaxis{90}
% The top side of a cube
\newcommand\topside[3]{
  \fill[fill=yellow,fill opacity=.7, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (0,1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The left side of a cube
\newcommand\leftside[3]{
  \fill[fill=green,fill opacity=.7, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (210:1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The right side of a cube
\newcommand\rightside[3]{
  \fill[fill=blue,fill opacity=.7, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (-30:1) --(0,-1)--(0,0);
}
% The cube 
\newcommand\cube[3]{
  \topside{#1}{#2}{#3} \leftside{#1}{#2}{#3} \rightside{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
% Definition of \planepartition
% To draw the following plane partition, just write \planepartition{ {a, b, c}, {d,e} }.
%  a b c
%  d e
\newcommand\planepartition[2][0]{
 \setcounter{x}{-1}
  \foreach \a in {#2} {
        \addtocounter{x}{1}
        \setcounter{y}{-1}
            \foreach \b in \a {
            \addtocounter{y}{1}
            \setcounter{z}{-1}
            \addtocounter{z}{#1} %partition of the desired floor (layer)
            \ifnum \b>0
            \foreach \c in {1,...,\b} {
                \addtocounter{z}{1}
                \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}
      }\fi
    }
  }
}
\begin{document} 


\begin{tikzpicture}% Old syntax is functional
\planepartition{{2,1,2,1,2,1,2},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{2,1,2,1,2,1,2}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}% The optional argument allow to build layer by layer
\planepartition{{1,1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,1,0,1,1}}
\planepartition[1]{{1,0,1,0,1,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0,1}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Both your code and marmot`s work fine.

Comment: Thank you, my way of doing things allows you to place several holes on the same column.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I added an optional parameter which indicates how many boxes are to be skipped. So `2/1` means two boxes but skip the first one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% to suppresses (hide) navigation symbols bar
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% Three counters
\newcounter{x}
\newcounter{y}
\newcounter{z}
% The angles of x,y,z-axes
\newcommand\xaxis{210}
\newcommand\yaxis{-30}
\newcommand\zaxis{90}
% The top side of a cube
\newcommand\topside[3]{
  \fill[fill=yellow, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (0,1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The left side of a cube
\newcommand\leftside[3]{
  \fill[fill=green, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (210:1) --(150:1)--(0,0);
}
% The right side of a cube
\newcommand\rightside[3]{
  \fill[fill=blue, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},shift={(\yaxis:#2)},
  shift={(\zaxis:#3)}, opacity=.7] (0,0) -- (30:1) -- (-30:1) --(0,-1)--(0,0);
}
% The cube 
\newcommand\cube[3]{
  \topside{#1}{#2}{#3} \leftside{#1}{#2}{#3} \rightside{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\newcommand\planepartition[1]{
 \setcounter{x}{-1}
  \foreach \a in {#1} {
\addtocounter{x}{1}
\setcounter{y}{-1}
\foreach \b/\d in \a {
  \addtocounter{y}{1}
  \setcounter{z}{-1}
 \ifnum\b>0
  \ifnum\b=\d
   \foreach \c in {1,...,\b} {
    \addtocounter{z}{1}
    \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}}
   \else
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cmin}{1+\d}
   \addtocounter{z}{\d}
   \foreach \c in {\cmin,...,\b} {
    \addtocounter{z}{1}
    \cube{\value{x}}{\value{y}}{\value{z}}}
   \fi
  \fi}}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\planepartition{{2,1,2/1,1,2/1,1,2},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{2,1,2/1,1,2/1,1,2}}%1st column from back to front{row1,... from left to right}%0 is the same as 2% it does not allow void for 0
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let me mention that in the above the old syntax is, of course, still functional. So if you drop the `/1` you will get the original result. But with this method you do not have to draw two partitions.

Comment: Which /1 are you referring to?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. Would you please give me the whole code.

Comment: I am sorry your answer was not displayed when I posted my comment. I followed your answer and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both your answer and AndréC`s work fine. I am confused about which answer to  mark!!!