# Problem generalizing a tikz example

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to extend a [tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/plane-partition/). So I did this :

```
\newcommand\topside[7]{
  \draw[fill=#7!50!white, draw=black,shift={(\xaxis:#1)},
  shift={(\yaxis:#2)}, shift={(\zaxis:#3)}]
  (0,0) -- ++(\yaxis:{-#5}) -- ++(\xaxis:{-#4}) -- ++(\yaxis:#5) --
  ++(\xaxis:#4); 
}
```

and so on. Basically, I used #1, #2 and #3 as the coordinates of the nearest corner, like the example, #4, #5, #6 for the sizes of the sides, and #7 the color of the face.

My problem : when I ask for drawing a parallepiped, nothing is drawn.

Could you help me on this one ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/plane-partition/

Comment: I have modified Jang Soo Kim's code several times. Here to allow not to build any cube in a part of the partition: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470653/138900
here to make holes: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470985/138900
and here to partially modify some angles and lengths: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499764/138900